# Select from 2 tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

I would like to select last record from 1 table for each ID section connected with another table. Connection between those tables is: notes.user_id = application_forms.id
and then notes.post_by_id = application_forms.user_id
I would like to select last record for each notes.user_id so I can display different CSS on the fonts depending on which user enter some notes, hope it's clear, if not I am here

1st Table

```
CREATE TABLE notes (
  note_id int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  note_when timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  user_id int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  post_by_id int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  note text,
  PRIMARY KEY (note_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

2nd Table

```
CREATE TABLE application_forms (
  id int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT  application_forms.online_offline, application_forms.online_offline2, application_forms.property_full_address, application_forms.submission_status, application_forms.employers_reference, application_forms.landlord_reference, application_forms.comp_by_app, application_forms.notes, application_forms.decision, application_forms.id, n.post_by_id FROM application_forms  LEFT  JOIN (SELECT user_id , MAX(note_id) , notes.post_by_id FROM notes) as n
             ON  n.user_id = application_forms.id

Comment: it's just doesnt work :(

Comment: can you post some example rows of both tables and of the result table?

Comment: there is table for notes and table for "applications" - each application can have unlimited notes, now I am trying to display different CSS for Notes Text to know which user wrote last note

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group